# Using Effect.ts Services

Tags: typescript

I have the following service definition:

```
export interface NextApiService {
  readonly next: Effect.Effect<
    never,
    never,
    {req: NextApiRequest; res: NextApiResponse}
  >
}

export const NextApiService = Context.Tag<NextApiService>(
  '@home/NextApiService',
)
```

which I am trying to consumer in the following pipe:

```
const program = (generalEnquiryDate: string) =>
  NextApiService.pipe(
    withParentAccountRefs,
    redemptionsApiEffect(generalEnquiryDate),
  )
```

But I am seeing the following TS compilation error and I am not sure what I am doing wrong:

```bash
The 'this' context of type 'Tag<NextApiService, NextApiService>' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type '{ req: NextApiRequest; res: NextApiResponse<any>; }'.

Type 'Tag<NextApiService, NextApiService>' is missing the following properties from type '{ req: NextApiRequest; res: NextApiResponse<any>; }': req, res
```